# Get values from JSON file and sort by key number value

Tags: javascript, json

I was wondering if someone could help me get this to work so it prints out values and sorts them by propertyCount, highest to lowest. Below gets me the the first 6 values from a JSON file.

Basically, Im trying to only grab 6 values from a JSON file where it's sorted by a key called count that has a number value. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```js
var countyInfo = [];
var count = 0;
var propertyCount = 0;

function getCountyInfo($j) {
  //$j.ajax({
  //  url: "/info.json?st=WA"
  //}).done(function(data) {
    //countyInfo = data;
    countyInfo = getDataDemo();
    $j.each(countyInfo.counts.county_info, function(key, value) {

      $j.each(value, function(key, value) {

        if (key == "count") {
          propertyCount = value;
        }

        if (key == "countyName" && value != null) {
          var countyName = value;
          if (count < 6) {
            $j('#countyList').append('<li class="topCountyRow">' + countyName + ' (' + propertyCount + ')</li>');
          }
          count++;
        }
      });
    });
  //});

}

(function($j) {
  //loaded();
  var county_info = [];
  getCountyInfo($j);
})(jQuery);

// Just for the StackOverflow Question
function getDataDemo() {
  return JSON.parse(`{
    "state": "wa",
    "stateName": "Washington",
    "counts": {
      "county_info": [
        {
        "count": 72,
        "countyName": "Anderson"
        },
        {
        "count": 43,
        "countyName": "Angelina"
        }
      ]
    }
  }`);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="countyList" class="ulTwoColumns"></ul>
```

Comment: what does the ```data``` object look like? Is it an object or an array?

Comment: I updated with a sample of what JSON looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sort function of array where you need to pass comparer function as below.

```
function sort(data)
{
    return  data.counts.county_info.sort((left,right)=>{
    return left.count<right.count?1:-1;
  })
}
```

Updated as per your data.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `sort` method to compare and sort

```
data.counts.county_info.sort(a, b => a.count < b.count);
```

Implementing in your code above

```
function getCountyInfo(){
    $j.ajax({
        url: "/info.json?st=WA"
    }).done(function(data) {        
        let sortedData = data.counts.county_info.sort(a, b => a.count < b.count);
         // other things to do
    });
}
```